# FIltering data in entity using two other entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4

I have following three data tables:

```
public partial class category
{
    public category()
    {
        this.subcategory = new HashSet<subcategory>();
    }

    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<subcategory> subcategory { get; set; }
}
```

Second Entity is

```
 public partial class subcategory
    {
        public subcategory()
        {
            this.tracked_item = new HashSet<item>();
        }

        public int subcategory_id { get; set; }
        public int category_id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; } 
        public virtual ICollection<item> item { get; set; }
        public virtual category category { get; set; }
    }
```

Third Entity

```
public partial class item
{
    public int item_id { get; set; }
    public string serial_number { get; set; }
    public string inventory_number { get; set; }
    public int subcategory_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> manu_id { get; set; }}
    public virtual subcategory subcategory { get; set; }
    public virtual manu manu { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to write a method in my web api where I want to filter data using three parameters like this 
using item as context

```
public IEnumerable<filteredItems> GetfilterItem(int category_id, int subcategory_id, int manu_id)
{
  return DbSet.Where(c=>c.category_id=category_id && c.subcategory_id && subcategory_id && c.manu_id =manu_d).Select(d=> new filteredItems() {
 ----
}:
```

Problem I have is on `.Where(c=>c.category_id=category_id && c.subcategory_id && subcategory_id && c.manu_id =manu_d)`    Intellisense wont go pass `category_id` it is not able to go to `subcategory_id` and `manu_id`

Please let me know how to write this query properly so I can filter data based on three variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

1. `==` is to show equivalence. `=` is for assigning.

   1. So `c.category_id=category_id` should be `c.category_id==category_id`
2. `c.subcategory_id && subcategory_id` looks like a typo.

   1. Should probably use `==` instead of `&&`

So your code would be:

```
public IEnumerable<filteredItems> GetfilterItem(int category_id, 
                                                int subcategory_id, 
                                                int manu_id)
{
  return DbSet.Where(c=>c.category_id == category_id 
                     && c.subcategory_id == subcategory_id 
                     && c.manu_id == manu_d)
              .Select(d=> new filteredItems {
                                              ----
                                            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using `=` instead of `==`, so you're not doing a comparison.

Secondly, you have a `&&` between `c.subcategory_id` and `subcategory_id`, instead of `==`.

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<filteredItems> GetfilterItem(int category_id, int subcategory_id, int manu_id)
{
    return DbSet.Where(c => c.category_id == category_id
                            && c.subcategory_id == subcategory_id
                            && c.manu_id == manu_d)
                .Select(d => new filteredItems
                                 {
                                     // populate object
                                 };
}
```